# Ghost Posts API & Newsletters

Tags: ghost-blog

Running Ghost 5.2.2 and using the Admin API to publish posts.

Alongside publishing the post via the API, I want it to send it out to a specified newsletter.

As far as I can tell from the Ghost documentation (https://ghost.org/docs/admin-api/#publishing-and-scheduling-posts) all I need to do is add ?newsletter={{newsletter-slug}} to the query string when I create the post. However it schedules the post, but doesn't schedule/send the email.

Everything appears to be working well (in terms of scheduling and publishing posts), just not sending out the emails.

What am I missing?

**Sample HTTPS request:**

**URL:** {{website-url}}/ghost/api/admin/posts/?newsletter=default-newsletter&source=html

**Method:** POST

**Body:** {"posts": [{"title": "Title","status": "scheduled","html": "Content","published_at": "2022-06-15T20:07:00.000Z"}]}

**Headers:**

- Content-Type: application/json
- Authorization: Ghost {{token}}

Answer (score -1):

You need setup mail service it's required in production.

Check out the documentation here https://ghost.org/docs/config/#mail

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).